# What exactly is the proper way to Parse JSON from URL in Android?

Tags: android, json

So I currently have a small django server spitting JSON out that I would like to read in my android app.
the JSON objects just have a string for a name, and two integers('likes', and 'dislikes).
I have looked up examples of how to do this but everything I find seems to be deprecated or just plain not work. I have counted 4 different ways to do it, but none that work, or at the very least explain whats going on for me to understand.
I just started with android and I am thoroughly confused and frustrated. I am use to c# and python but android is making me feel like a complete beginner again.

Can someone please walk me through the step by step how to connect to a URL and get the JSON from it and explain what it all does?
this is the first time I have ever felt I needed to ask a question on something like this :/

Comment: take a look at this tutorial which shows [How to request data from URL using Volley library and then parse it](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/)

Comment: Best to use Androids networking library. https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) library, which uses [okhttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) to make a network request and you can use [retrofit converters](https://github.com/square/retrofit/wiki/Converters) to serialize your json to java object

Comment: so im trying to look through retrofit. can you tell me whats happening here, help me understand. "@GET("user")
Call<User> getUser(@Header("Authorization") String authorization)".

Comment: Lets say that you have this interface
public interface GitHubService {
@GET("users/{user}/repos")
Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
You can create a retrofit client using this code
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.github.com/").build();
and get your api client
GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
and when you call listRepos method
Call<List<Repo>> repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
you send GET request to https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos and parse the json into java object of type List<Repo>

Comment: in your exaple you will send GET request to {yourApiServer}/user and the method param will jsut add http header Authorization:{yourString} and the result will be parsed into object of type User

Answer (score 0):

If you are a newbie just go through the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html) on how to perform network connectivity.

Some of the Recommended libs for network and JSON parsing include

- [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/): provide easy to use methods to perform network operations and object serialization (supports gson)
- [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson): A powerful Java serialization/deserialization library to convert Java Objects into JSON and back
- [volley](https://github.com/google/volley) alternative to retrofit, developed by Google, watch this official [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo)